# Talend Open Studio: Authenticate to REST API

Tags: json, rest, post, get, talend

I am currently building an ETL job in Talend Open Studio, that calls a banking API in order to retrieve customer data. The API works with OAuth 2.0. Using Postman, I can easily get an Access Token, which I then use in Talend to retrieve the customer data in JSON format. However, before I get the access token, the customer whose data I want to pull from the API, has to grant me permission for doing so. Using Postman, this is easy enough, as I get redirected to a page where the customer enters his/her credentials and then gives my App permission to pull the data:
[image]

My plan was, to setup the Talend job in a way, that this gets done automatically. My current approach is to use a tRESTClient component which calls the page on above screenshot and enters the credentials. Now there are several options with the tRESTClient component, but none of it works. First I tried to make a GET call with "Use Authentication Basic HTTP", parsing username and password of the user. That does not end with an error, but the response is just the html of the login page itself. When I try to make a POST call parsing the customer credentials to the TRESTClient component in JSON format, I am getting a 400 Bad Request. This is how my component looks in this case:
[image]

I also asked that question in the Talend Community forum, but so far no one replied to it. I dont know if I am completely off-trail here?! Any hint would be greatly appreciated, I am struggling with that task for 3 days now...

EDIT: to be more straightforward:Is it possible to perform these 2 steps in Talend alone:
[image]

Comment: The API you are trying to use requires the user to give you permission to allow you to act on their behalf. If you were able to automate this process, don't you think this would be a major security issue?

Comment: Hi Evert, thank for your reply. Well, now that you are mentioning it...I guess you have a point :)  The API doc mentions, that once the user has granted permission for the API feature in question (in my case it would be reading transaction info), the step with the authorization can be skipped. However, the way I understand it, you get an authorization code once the user grants you permission. This code you use to retrieve the access token. Problem is, I dont ever get to see this auth code. When I call the API via Postman, I get redirected directly. Is there a way to save the code somewhere?

Comment: You save the access token and refresh token, the 'authorization code' can only be used once.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. Since both tokens expire after a few minutes, I need to get a new authorization code every time they have expired, therefore I need the users permission on a regular basis?

Comment: No, you use the refresh token to get a new access token every time the access token expires. This is the single purpose of the refresh token.

Comment: hm ok, I will need to take another look I suppose. The refresh token I was given by the API expires after 12 minutes instead of 6, if I looked correctly. But thanks a lot for your help, things are way clearer now!

Comment: in that case it would be a good idea to schedule a refresh operation every 10 minutes or so.